# Testing critical points using newton-raphson method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a homework assignment for my artificial intelligence course and I became a bit stuck on one part.

The problem asks to retrieve the optima of the function and then to tell for each optima whether it is a minimum or a maximum.

The function is as follows:
$$
f(x,y,z) = x \ln x + y \ln y + z \ln z + \alpha(x + y + z - 1)
$$

The gradient was calculated to be:
$$
\nabla f(x,y,z) = (\ln x + \alpha + 1)\vec{i} + (\ln y + \alpha + 1)\vec{j} + (\ln z + \alpha + 1)\vec{k}
$$

In order to find the critical points I then set $\nabla f(x,y,z) = 0 $, which gave me the following critical points:

$$
(0,0,0),(\frac{1}{e^{\alpha + 1}},\frac{1}{e^{\alpha + 1}},\frac{1}{e^{\alpha + 1}}),(1,1,1)
$$

What is the best approach to test if each critical point it is a maximum or a minimum in the function?

I also have calculated the Hessian matrix for an earlier part of this problem. The hessian matrix came to be:

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{x} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{y} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{z} \end{array} \right]
$$

Is there a way to utilize the hessian matrix to test for convexity at those points and therefore if convex it is a minimum?  The problem with that thought was that when I calculated it out they all turned out to be minimums which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Try graphing the function. Use Wolfram Alpha, for example. A picture is worth ...

Comment: You've missed 24 stationary points.

Comment: Can you explain how you came to 24?

Comment: Minima are when the Hessian is Positive Definite. Maxima = Negative Definite. Very easy to check for a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @bubba this is a 4d equation it didn't graph too nicely.  Or do you mean to graph the gradient vector?

Comment: $$x,y,z\in\{0,e^{-a-1},1\}$$ produces $3^3$ possibilities.

Comment: There are ways to graph this sort of function (using color to indicate the function value, for example). But, in truth, I didn't notice that itwas 4D. Apologies. My mistake. Anyway, the Hessian approach is the right one. The graph serves only to give you some insight (if it's comprehensible).

Comment: @bubba no worries, honest mistake.  Normally I'm used to the graph approach as well. The methodology with the hessian matrix is new to me.

Comment: @JeffSnider Based on the hessian matrix, wouldn't all of those turn out to be a minimums since all of the points are positive values of x,y and z.

Comment: Should a point that results as infinity when plugged into the hessian matrix result in a minimum or maximum?  My thought is that it is greater than 0 but is positive definite and therefore convex -> and therefore a minimum.

Comment: The condition at 0 is hard to make sense of.  The $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x$ exists and is 0, but at the point itself $x\ln x$ does not exist.  Technically there is no maximum at 0, although the function is bounded above as it approaches 0.

Comment: Also at 1 there is no stationary point.

Comment: @JeffSnider so then for the points that involve 0 are they not a maximum or minimum? Would not 1 be a stationary point because $ln(x)=0$?

Comment: You need $\ln x + \alpha +1=0$, which $x=1$ does not satisfy.

I would treat 0 carefully -- indicate it is not in the domain but show how in the limit it's a maximum.

Comment: The point (1,1,1) would still be a stationary point since it is a bound of the domain. Correct?  Im still a bit confused on how to treat 0 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky around 0.  Here is how I would approach it:

The Jacobian is $$\nabla f(x,y,z)=(\ln x+\alpha +1)i+(\ln y+\alpha +1)j+(\ln z+\alpha +1)k.$$

First note that $x,y,z=0$ is not in the domain, but this function has a value in the limit: $$\lim_{x\to0^+} (x\ln x+\alpha x)=0.$$  We treat points where some or all of $x,y,z=0$ as though they *are* in the domain, because to exclude them means there is no optimum near $(0,0,0)$ although the function is increasing as $x,y,z\to 0^+$ and bounded above in the local region.  This means that $(0,0,0)$ is a local maximum: any point with $x,y,z<0$ does not exist, and any nearby point with $x,y,z>0$ takes a smaller value.

We have stationary points for all $x,y,z\in\{0,e^{-\alpha-1}\}$.  This means we have $2^3=8$ stationary points to consider.

The Hessian is $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{1}{x}&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{y}&0\\0&0&\frac{1}{z}\end{array}\right).$$

We have determined we should treat $(0,0,0)$ as a **local maximizer**.  The Hessian is undefined here, but at a local maximizer it must be negative definite.  For a coordinate with a zero value (e.g., $x=0$) we treat that row of the Hessian as though it contains a negative value on the diagonal and is zero elsewhere.

Next consider $(e^{-\alpha-1},e^{-\alpha-1},e^{-\alpha-1})$.  At this point the Hessian has positive values along the diagonal and is zero elsewhere: it is positive definite.  Thus this point is a **local minimizer**.

Consider the remaining stationary points, where at least one coordinate is $0$ and at least one coordinate is $e^{-\alpha-1}$.  Here the Hessian has a positive value in diagonal in the row corresponding to $e^{-\alpha-1}$ and an effectively negative value in the row corresponding to $0$.  Hence these are all **saddle points**.

Since the function is unbounded above as $x,y,z\to\infty$ there is no global maximizer.  But the function is bounded below, hence $(e^{-\alpha-1},e^{-\alpha-1},e^{-\alpha-1})$ is the global minimizer.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense now.  Thanks!